# how to initialize an array with generics?

Tags: java, arrays, generics

I am implementing an interface in Java like this:

```
public interface Stack <E>{
    public int size();
    public boolean isEmpty();
```

the class that implements it:

```
public class StackArray<E> implements Stack<E>{
    private Object list[];
    private int top=-1;
    public StackArray(int n){
        list=new Object[n];
    }
```

this works quite well, so when I called it I do this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        StackArray<Students> st=new StackArray<>(4);
```

so how I can implement that, but using generics, I have tried this:

```
public class StackArray<E> implements Stack<E>{
    private E st[];
    private int top=-1;
    public StackArray(int n){
        st=(E[]) Array.newInstance(null, n);
    }
```

but I got a nullPointerException, is there a way to surpase this?

Comment: Which line throws the `NPE`?

Comment: I would suspect that the line `Array.newInstance(null, n);` throws the NPE, especially given that the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#newInstance(java.lang.Class,%20int)) says that it will...

Answer (score 1):

Because of [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), you at some point need to pass the actual class (or an actual object from which the class can be obtained via `getClass()`) when creating an array of objects. You cannot pass `null` as the first argument to `Array.newInstance`; you need an actual class. One way to do it is:

```
public class StackArray<E> implements Stack<E>{
    private E st[];
    private int top=-1;
    public StackArray(Class<E> type, int n) {
        st=(E[]) Array.newInstance(type, n);
    }
}
```

You would need to call this with the actual type, not `null`. For instance:

```
StackArray<Integer> stack = new StackArray<>(Integer.class, 20);
```

You could also declare the constructor as

```
    public StackArray(Class<? extends E> type, int n) {
```

but I don't see much advantage to that (and several risks).

However, in general it's a bad idea to mix arrays with generics. I suggest you rethink your design.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create generic arrays in Java.

You are getting a `NullPointerException` because of this line:

```
Array.newInstance(null, n);
```

From the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#newInstance%28java.lang.Class,%20int%29) for that method:

```
Parameters:
    componentType - the Class object representing the component type of the new array
    length - the length of the new array
Returns:
    the new array
Throws:
    NullPointerException - if the specified componentType parameter is null
    IllegalArgumentException - if componentType is Void.TYPE
    NegativeArraySizeException - if the specified length is negative
```

You can see that it states that it will throw a `NullPointerException` if `componentType` is `null`.

One **hack** is to create an `Object[]` and then cast it:

```
public StackArray(int n){
    st=(E[]) new Object[n];
}
```

I said hack because this is horrible and should be avoided. The best thing you can do is use the java collections API and change your class to

```
public class StackArray<E> implements Stack<E>{
    private List<E> st;
    private int top=-1;

    public StackArray(int n){
        st = new ArrayList<E>(n);
    }

    //...
}
```